# Change a buttons value if parameters are met, jQuery, PHP, Sessions

Tags: php, jquery, session

I have the following button:

```
<input type="button" count='<?php echo count($_SESSION['children']);?>' name="children" class="add_child" value="Add Another Child"/>
```

On default when the form loads (with a clean session) there is no input for children, so the button should read "Add a Child".

If there is a text field present with the name children[] then it should just display: "Add another Child".

How would this be done ?

I am using php / jquery / sessions for the fields here is the code for it:

```
   $('.add_child').click(function(){
    var attrName = $(this).attr('name');
    var count = $(this).attr('count');
    $(this).attr('count', (parseInt(count)+1))
    var input = $('<input />');
    input.attr('type','text')
    input.attr('name',attrName+"["+count+"]" ) 
    $('.children_form').append($('<li />').append(input));
    $('#content li:odd').addClass('alt');
})

<?php
    if(isset($_SESSION['children'])) {
    foreach($_SESSION['children'] as $index=>$child){ ?>

        <li>
        <?php echo "<input type='text' name='children[{$index}]' value='{$child}'/>";?>
        </li>

    <?php } }?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this out with the code you have already:

```
$('.add_child').click(function(){
  //code...
  $(this).val('Add Another Child');

})
```

and the php for the input:

```
<input type="button" count='<?php echo count($_SESSION['children']);?>'
     name="children" class="add_child" 
     value="<?php echo (isset($_SESSION['children'])? 
        'Add Another Child':'Add a Child');?>"
/>
```

Comment: How would this check if the input Children is present ?

Comment: its not. just when it is clicked it would change to add another child bc that button should have added a child.

Comment: i added the php for the input child

Comment: i was just trying that with a statement from yesterday thanks man!

Comment: ye sorry i was away from the machine :D